NextJS env variables causing errors when "git push"
I am using Next JS 14.2.5 and just testing out environmental variables. I made a .env.local file with
HI=poop
and in another file,
export const hi = () => {
console.log(process.env.HI);
return process.env.HI; };

In another file (with use client), I have this code:
import { hi } from "./serverAI";

const Main = () => {
   hi();
   return <div>poop</div>
}

In next.config.mjs, I have this following code:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    env: {
        HI: process.env.HI,
    },
};

export default nextConfig;

It is all fine, and poop is printing out in the console. However, when I git push it, it returns this error:
remote: error: GH013: Repository rule violations found for refs/heads/master.
remote:
remote: - GITHUB PUSH PROTECTION
remote:   —————————————————————————————————————————
remote:     Resolve the following violations before pushing again
remote:
remote:     - Push cannot contain secrets

How do I fix this error? Am I somehow pushing the env contents into the repo? My .gitignore has .env*.local so this should not be happening.
UPDATE:
I committed some code previously that had NEXT_PUBLIC in the env (I think that causes this error). However, I wasn't able to push it, due to the error. After I reverted the old commit and made a new one, it was all fine. Thanks for everybody's help.

First, nothing to do with Next.js (please remove tag). Next, Github is not pushing anything, you are. You need to remove whatever file you have added which contains  any secret from your commit

try add this in .gitignore
*.env
it shouldn't push to git with a filename that suffixes .env
